# How do I know that the time-step I'm using in my Verlet integrator is small enough?

Tags: computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

I am performing a molecular dynamics simulation of a many-body system using the Verlet algorithm in an implicit solvent, i.e. adding noise to the equation of motion via a thermostat term.

I want to tune my integration step to be as large as possible, without introducing any simulation artifacts. How do I know that my simulation step is not too large? What quantities should I monitor?

Comment: I asked a very similar question previously over on SciComp.SE: [Stable time step limits for Velocity-Verlet integration](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/stable-time-step-limits-for-velocity-verlet-integration)